# Как получить request.url для express серевера на русском языке?

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6

У меня есть сервер на express.js

```
app.get('/[acdrs]/*', async (req, res) => {
 ....
    const path = req.url
 ....   
})
```

У меня запрос может быть на любом языке, в том числе и на русском.

Например

```
/c/en/hello_worls
/c/ru/привет
```

и.т.д.

Когда я делаю запрос на рускком языке у меня req.url приходит закодированный.

```
/c/ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82
```

Как сделать так, что бы запросы, которые приходят на Русском языке не преобразовывались ?

Comment: Мне кажетстя, лучше смотреть в сторону того, как ```%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82``` задекодировать обратно в обычный юникод из  URI-escaped строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Некоторые старые системы могут не поддерживать работу с кириллицей в URL. В таких случаях можно использовать декодирование. Ниже пример как это делается на js:

```js
url = '/c/ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82'
url = decodeURIComponent(url)

console.log(url)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я так же сделал. Я думал, может быть есть какой то вариант, который позволял без этого метода, средствами express это сделать.